How do I get Ubuntu 23.10 to use Bcrypt or blowfish as default password hashing algorithm for new users that are created?
in login.defs, BCRYPT is listed as an option, but when I set ENCRYPT_METHOD BCRYPT, it doesn't work.
#If set to MD5, MD5-based algorithm will be used for encrypting password
#If set to SHA256, SHA256-based algorithm will be used for encrypting password
#If set to SHA512, SHA512-based algorithm will be used for encrypting password
#If set to BCRYPT, BCRYPT-based algorithm will be used for encrypting password
#If set to YESCRYPT, YESCRYPT-based algorithm will be used for encrypting password
#If set to DES, DES-based algorithm will be used for encrypting password (default)
#MD5 and DES should not be used for new hashes, see crypt(5) for recommendations.
#Overrides the MD5_CRYPT_ENAB option
#
#Note: It is recommended to use a value consistent with the PAM modules configuration.
#
ENCRYPT_METHOD BCRYPT

